# How to set a fixed random seed for the inner loop of nested hyper-parameter tuning?

Tags: mlr

I'm trying to do hyper-parameter tuning with nested crossvalidation. This is my inner loops for two learners lrn1 and lrn2:

```
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)

tune_lrn1 <- makeTuneWrapper(lrn1, resampling = inner, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)

tune_lrn2 <- makeTuneWrapper(lrn2, resampling = inner, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
```

Is there any way to set a fixed value of the random seed everytime before "inner" is instantiated, so that the two learners always use exactly the same data partitions for hyper-parameter evaluation?

Comment: `set.seed()` should do the job?

Comment: @pat-s this does not always work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you can do but they might not satisfiy your needs completely.

#### Fix the resampling for a given task

...or at least a given n. In this example we use the task `iris.task`.

```
inner_fixed = makeResampleInstance(inner, iris.task)
tune_lrn1 <- makeTuneWrapper(lrn1, resampling = inner_fixed, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
tune_lrn2 <- makeTuneWrapper(lrn2, resampling = inner_fixed, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
```

If you want to apply this for multiple tasks you have to solve it programmatically.

#### Setting the seed can fail!

The following setting is already the default

```
ctrl = makeTuneControl*(same.resampling.instance = TRUE, ...)
```

This means, that all tuning evaluations are evaluated on the same train/test split. In other words: `makeResampleInstance` is called at the very beginning of `tune()`. Now we can go with @pat-s answer, which does not always work because the RNG is used during train for some learners and accordingly the ongoing train/test-splits will "diverge":

```
library(mlr)
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)
task = iris.task
lrn1 = makeLearner("classif.rpart")
lrn2 = makeLearner("classif.svm")
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(same.resampling.instance = TRUE, budget = 4)

library(mlrHyperopt)
ps1 = getDefaultParConfig(lrn1)$par.set
ps2 = getDefaultParConfig(lrn2)$par.set

tune_lrn1 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn1, resampling = inner, par.set = ps1, control = ctrl)
tune_lrn2 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn2, resampling = inner, par.set = ps2, control = ctrl)
set.seed(1)
r1 = resample(tune_lrn1, resampling = cv10, task = iris.task, models = TRUE)
set.seed(1)
r2 = resample(tune_lrn2, resampling = cv10, task = iris.task, models = TRUE)

sapply(1:10, function(i) {
  identical(r2$models[[i]]$learner.model$opt.result$resampling$train.inds, r1$models[[i]]$learner.model$opt.result$resampling$train.inds)  
})

# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob, very helpful. In my case, the problem with the first approach (fix the ...) is that my outer is crossvalidation, so I cannot fix the inner instance. I guess I could use the second approach, but redefining function makeResampleInstance, as follows (yes, a very ugly solution, but ...)
 mlr::makeResampleInstance <- function (desc, task, size, ...) 
{
set.seed(1)
etc.
}